# Форматированный текст ActionText отображается с HTML тегами Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Всем привет! Добавляя в проект Action Text столкнулся со следующей проблемой: после форматирования текста на странице show он отображается некорректно: [image: Отображение Action text]

Настраивал Action Text [по этому сайту](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html), а также по паре видео на ютубе. Мой **articles/show.html.slim:**

```
h1 =@article.title

=@article.body
```

**application.scss:**

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

**application.js:**

```
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"
```

Стили все загружены, сама форма работает корректно, но не отображается текст

UPD:

Попробовал [SanitizeHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html), но вылезает ошибка

> no implicit conversion of ActionText::RichText into String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло банальное `=sanitize @article.body.to_s`, до чего не дошёл сразу почему-то